# could not open chrome browser in R

Tags: r, rselenium

I use `RSelenium` package for web scraping and I have worked with this code from 2 weeks ago and it was worked.

`library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(port=4444L,browser="chrome")
remote_driver <- driver$client`

but I had some issue in another project so I had to update all my packages.
so after that when I am trying to work with the same code I get this error

`Could not open chrome browser. Client error message: Summary: SessionNotCreatedException Detail: A new session could not be created. Further Details: run errorDetails method Check server log for further details.`

and sometimes this error

`Error in wdman::selenium(port = port, verbose = verbose, version = version,  : Selenium server signals port = 4444 is already in use.`

I don't know if that because I updated the packages or what?

any help?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still looking for an Answer as this is nearly 6 month old Q'n.

But just cross check if you have set Chrome path correctly in environment variables or not.

You can do it by running simple command in cmd prompt > Chrome on windows-10
[image: running this will open a blank chrome browser window as given below in background]

if not done then you'll get an error says-
'chrome' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file'.

then you have to add chrome installable path to environment variables as below-
in win-10
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

In case you don't know how to do this- it can be done as per below snap.

[image: how to add chrome to PATH..]

Hope this Helps..!!

Comment: I have used another approach but it may be helpful for someone have faced the same problem thank you

Comment: @Fatima I face the same problem. what is your approach?

Comment: @nurandi I have used webharvy software